# Racks-Quandles theory tag

Tags: feature-request, tagging

I considered creating [racks-quandles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/racks-quandles) tag for questions about [racks and quandles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racks_and_quandles) which appear in knot theory.

Can be this an useful tag? I wanted to put it in my question when I've discovered that I have not enough reputation points to [create tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

Is this at least the right place for this question ?

Comment: Might it be useful? I'm not certain. "Quandle" hasn't appeared in many [questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=quandle+is%3Aquestion) thus far. If this is something you want, perhaps use your question to make a case for this tag.

Comment: @ArthurFischer I've found at least 7 different question about this topic or where the quandles appear + my last question that is only about conjugation quandles. What I know is that I worked with "quandles" when I did not even know about quandle terminology: that is my fault but seems to me like deleting monoid tag only because there is already the semigroup tag and monoids are a special kind of semigroups. I may be wrong but I'd find it very confortable because quandles and rack are not reducible to knot theory tag.

Comment: I'll add link to a [discussion in chat about this tag](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/on-tags-for-racks-and-quandles).